# Confusion about maximal and closed itemsets in association rules

Tags: association-rules

So I'm studying association rules and Apriori algorithm for my data science class. There's a section about compactness (compact representation of frequent itemsets). I'm not sure whether I'm not getting something here or I'm constantly encountering plain mistakes (this professor is known for making a lot of mistakes in his literature, and they are just slides anyway, not a book or anything).

It starts with a couple of definitions and some corollaries (I had to google English equivalents to the following terms, I hope I got them right).

**Definition 1:** An itemset is maximal frequent if none of its direct supersets is frequent.

*Possible mistake #1*: It is not explicitly mentioned that it has to be a frequent itemset (while other sources mention it).

Then a corollary is stated:

**Corollary:** If $X$ is a maximal frequent itemset then all of its subsets are frequent.

*Possible mistake #2:* Okay so not technically a mistake but rather stating the obvious, because this should apply to frequent itemsets in general and is not specific to the maximal frequent ones.

**Definition 2:** An itemset $X$ is closed if none of its direct supersets has the same support as $X$.

And a corollary to that definition:

**Corollary:** All subsets of a closed itemset have the same support.

*Possible mistake #3:* Reason 1: This corollary just 'sounds' very incorrect. Reason 2: Okay so let's assume that we got a set $X = \{A, B, C, D\}$ and let's say it has some support $s_X$. If we were to assume that $X$ is closed that would only tell us that every one of its direct **supersets** ($\{A, B, C, D, E\}, \{A, B, C, D, Z\}$, etc...) has the support that is not equal to $s_X$ (actually it would be strictly less than $s_X$ but it doesn't matter). I don't see how this tells us anything about $X$'s **subsets**?

At one point I thought it might just be me misunderstanding everything. But then comes an example. Since all the item names are in my language, and showing you the original would make it very unpleasant to read, I've replaced names with letters and I've also shortened the example because the mistake (*Possible mistake #4*) is at the very beginning. So it reads:

> In the following example, the itemsets that are bolded are **maximal frequent**:
> $$\begin{matrix} \text{itemset} & \text{support count} \\
> A & 4 \\
> \mathbf{B} & 5 \\
> C & 3 \\
> D & 4 \\ 
> \mathbf{\{A, B\}} &  4 \\
> \text{etc...}
> \end{matrix}$$

*Surely an overlook #1:* Support threshold is not mentioned.

*Possible mistake #4:* Aside from that, recalling the maximal frequent itemset definition (**Definition 1** here) it states that in order for an itemset to be maximal frequent none of its direct supersets can be frequent. If I'm to trust other sources (*Possible mistake #1*) it means that a maximal frequent itemset has to be frequent to begin with. In this example, since $\{A, B\}$ is bolded (meaning it's maximal frequent) then it is frequent. But that would mean that $B$ cannot be maximal frequent because it has a frequent direct superset. And that is in contradiction with this example.

Am I misunderstanding something here or are these all really mistakes?

Thanks.